# Refrigerator on a shared electric line with Stove and 5 countertop outlets

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, refrigerator, nec

When we moved in our new construction home the dedicated fridge outlet in the kitchen was faulty.

The builder sent his electrician who said the the entire line has an issue so they did a connection from the adjacent counter top outlets + gas stove line. So now GFCI 5 counter outlets + gas stove + refrigerator shares the same line. They also relabeled the circuit box.

I think this is a quick hack and wondering if this will affect resale value down the road or fail inspection. The electrician said that it is as per the NEC code and running a new line will cause 20 plus drywall holes or so. Since we are under warranty all these fixes will be covered but I was wondering if it’s worth poking those holes for a dedicated line.

If we leave it this way is it going to jeopardize future sale or inspection failed because the fridge did not have a dedicated outlet. Does this affect resale value?

Answer (score 3):

The refrigerator outlet being shared with countertop outlets is fine, and very common in older houses.  However, there are some advantages to having the refrigerator be on a dedicated circuit.  The primary advantage is that you're at no risk of some other device tripping the breaker, and you don't turn it back on right away for whatever reason, not realizing that your food is spoiling.  The other advantage is that if you ever install a backup power source, such as a generator, it's much easier to wire that to keep your food save through power outages.  It's up to you whether this is worth breaking out the drywall for or not.

Comment: It’s a gas stove. The electrician said that the only electric power that it needs is during ignition. It’s just a cooktop and does not have an oven attached

Comment: But the counter top outlets could draw significant amps if you have (or will have) a microwave, toaster oven, coffee maker, or any appliance with a motor (e.g., blender). Best to dedicate a line to the fridge, IMO

Answer (score 0):

The question is about resale value.

In some jurisdictions like Canada, or in the US where there is an applicable code amendments, the kitchen refrigerators must be on their own circuit. The same may apply to a garburator, or dishwasher circuit. Gas stoves can share a circuit.

A home inspector (for sales - not electrical inspection) likely won't find that issue: they don't check loads & circuits unless there is an obvious and visible reason to dig deeper.

Whether you disclose it is a different matter.

Cleaning the fridge spotless will do much for your resale value!

Comment: Wrong -- there may be a *local* amendment where you're at that requires the fridge to be on its own circuit, but the NEC *expressly* permits it to be on a kitchen countertop (small appliance) branch circuit, as per 210.52(B)(1): "In the kitchen, pantry, breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling unit, the
two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits
required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and floor receptacle outlets covered by 210.52(A), all countertop outlets covered
by 210.52(C), and receptacle outlets for refrigeration equipment."

Comment: (Note also that the common case of the fridge being on its own circuit is covered by Exception 2 to 210.52(B)(1), BTW.)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel actually good point, I was referring to the Canadian code and thought it applied to N.Amer in general. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a good bead on the situation and that the circuit was already butchered with the stove. So absolutely, document your complaint, who responded and how along with a call and/or visit by whatever (could be City, Township or County) Code Inspector.

Your investment should be taken seriously, especially when "professionals" only take their shortcuts seriously...which is ALWAYS.

Definitely, raise a stink, make some waves and burn those bridges while you can for anything and everything out of whack. Your documentation then goes with the house that you never had a problem with and your price can be confidently top-dollar firm.